# Mysql subquery optimization - how to reduce/remove subqueries

Tags: mysql

After multiple passes on this, I'm wondering if it's possible to optimize this query any further? Any insights are greatly appreciated. Besides having to use a bunch of subqueries which is not ideal, I have to use one of them twice as the 'tags' reference can't be used in the where clause... (Haven't been able to figure out how to rewrite this as a join to address that)

```
SELECT `t1`.*, 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tag_id) FROM media_tag WHERE media_id=t1.id GROUP BY media_id ) as tags, 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(award_id) FROM media_award WHERE media_id=t1.id GROUP BY media_id ) as awards, 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(client_id) FROM media_client WHERE media_id=t1.id GROUP BY media_id ) as clients, 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(collaborator_id) FROM media_collaborator t2 LEFT JOIN collaborator t3 ON t2.collaborator_id=t3.id WHERE media_id=t1.id AND t3.collaborator_type_id='1' GROUP BY media_id ) as agencies, 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(collaborator_id) FROM media_collaborator t2 LEFT JOIN collaborator t3 ON t2.collaborator_id=t3.id WHERE media_id=t1.id AND t3.collaborator_type_id<>'1' GROUP BY media_id ) as collaborators, 
`t2`.`idx`, `t2`.`type` 
FROM (`media` t1) 
LEFT JOIN `sort` t2 ON `t1`.`id`=`t2`.`id` AND t2.type="media" 
WHERE 
    FIND_IN_SET('1',(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tag_id) FROM media_tag WHERE media_id=t1.id GROUP BY media_id )) 
    AND IF(t2.tag_id IS NOT NULL,t2.tag_id='1',1) 
GROUP BY `t1`.`id` 
ORDER BY `t1`.`date_mod` DESC, `title` ASC, `t2`.`idx` ASC, `date_mod` DESC, `title` ASC
```

Comment: I would probably throw that away. Have a rethink of what is trying to be achieved. As you have not told us it would be difficult to give a sensible answer

Comment: I have a main collection of 'media' records. Each of the subqueries are pulling in indexed attributes living in different tables. Attribute tables have a schema of (id,media_id,name). The goal is to query the main media files, be able to aggregate attributes into comma separated lists and then abe able to filter on a given value in any one of those attribute lists

Comment: I'm curious if there is a better way to setup a schema for this type of data format?

Comment: I just think that if you need a query this complicated then either have a rethink of the query of perhaps the structure of your database is wrong.

Comment: Understood and I agree. Maybe this should be a separate SO post but now I'm wondering what the optimal table structure is for this type of data format (main records table with multiple 1-to-many attribute relationships)

Comment: That is a lot of work that most people on the MB would not consider to do for free. Would take about half a day to take into account your other queries etc.

Answer (score 2):

you should try to minimize select statements for each row , you could join that rows and group by some identifiers , it would be better if you could post your table structures and tell us what info do u want from them ...

Comment: ... And then rethink a better solution

Comment: I have a main 'media' table of records. I have separate tables of different attribute types (id,name) and I have a table that maps any attribute to a media record (attribute_id,media_id). Want to query 'media' records with aggregated lists of attributes and be able to filter on specific attributes. Per my knowledge, the structure I'm using makes sense but I'm wondering if there is perhaps a smarter table structure for this data format?